# what is difference between these two code checks for null

Tags: c#

I see  different styles of coding as below

```
1) 

Method1(object ob)
{
  if(ob == null)
    return;

  // do something
}

Method2(object ob)
{
  if(ob != null)
  {
    // do something
    return;
  }

}
```

What is difference between above those two methods.Some people check null value and return and some they check with not equall to null;

Do we need to check == null or not equall to null??

Comment: It's a matter of coding style.

Comment: I, for ex, don't like many nested blocks and prefer the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a matter of style.  It likely won't make a difference either way (and in fact may even compile down to the same IL).

The only difference is how the code looks.  The second one has an extra level of indentation.  Rather than surrounding the entire body of a method by the if statement some programmers will prefer to just return from the method and remove that extra tab.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that it really depends on what the methods are doing. `Method 1` is simply checking if the value is null while `Method 2` is only doing something to `obj` if it has a value.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine that if it makes more sense logically to compare if something is null

bool thing;  // defaults to false

if(!thing) { } // checks for false

int a = 1;
int b = 2;

if(a ==b ) { //false}

if(a != b) { //true }

Comment: if(!thing) {} doesn't compile in C# (but I'm not the one who down-voted you, FYI).

Comment: @Colin thing is a boil so !bool does compile

Comment: Ah, gotcha. I skimmed over the declaration and assumed he was using "object" instead of "bool" like the OP did.

Comment: Not sure why anyone would have down-voted your answer. :-/ I up-voted it for balance since it seems correct and informative.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty much strictly stylistic, as long as you aren't planning on doing anything else in the function if obj is null.

Option 1 can be nice because it reduces overall nesting (i.e. with option two, you end up with the entire body of the function nested inside of the then clause)

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that "ob==null" compiles, while "ob=!null" is nonsense.

I assume you mean to compare "==" to "!=".

For "ob==null", the conditional will be true if ob is null (so the code block beneath it will run in that case).

For "ob!=null", the conditional will be true if ob is NOT null.